# How to add any WMS layer on Google Earth Plugin in my web application?

Tags: wms, google-earth

I have a GIS application which allows user to draw features on Google Earth plugin included on my web application.

Now i want to give an option of adding any wms layer on the google earth plugin if needed.

I searched on the internet for answers but the only solution was through **Image Overlay** option which is not available on google earth plugin.